# error: package android.support.v7.internel.widget does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed an android application(API 23) but it does not work .I  found this error:

```
  E:\AllInOne1\app\src\main\java\eniso\ia32\Rabie\allinone\spinnerActivity.java
  Error:(3, 42)
 error: package android.support.v7.internal.widget does not    exist
  Error:(4, 60) error: package    android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat does not exist
  Error:(8, 65) error: cannot find symbol class OnItemSelectedListener
  Error:(23, 30) error: cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat
  Error:(30, 33) error: cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat
  Error:(22, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a     supertype
  Error:(29, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a   supertype
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

that's **build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "eniso.ia32.Rabie.allinone"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    }
```

I have installed "android support library"  but it does not work

that's **snipperActivity.java**:

```
 package eniso.ia32.Rabie.allinone;

import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import   android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class spinnerActivity extends TourismActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you show relevant code of `spinnerActivity.java`?

Comment: why do you have the same `compile` twice ?